# Why does HDFS throw unexpected EOF error using golang?

Tags: go, hdfs

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/colinmarc/hdfs"
)
func main() { 
    client, err := hdfs.New("192.168.0.38:50070")
    fs, err := client.ReadDir("/")
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(fs)
}
```

err is unexpected EOF
And I found that the error occurs in

```
func (c *NamenodeConnection) readResponse(method string, resp proto.Message) error {
...
    _, err = io.ReadFull(c.conn, packet)
...
}
```

I'm using hadoop 2.7.3

Answer (score 2):

I've found the reason. I was using the WEBHDFS Port (50070) instead of the Hadoop IPC Port (9000).